# Problem with AWS Cognito function not being called within VPC

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create an identity pool user from a lambda function, but every time I try to use cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity the function times out.

When it was outside of a VPC it was working fine, but when I locked down the database and moved the lamdba into a public VPC to access the DB it stopped working. Other lambda functions in the same subnet connect to the DB and our website just fine.

The lambda has AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole, AmazonCognitoPowerUser, 
and AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities. The subnet is completely public.

code where it times out:

```
var openIdParams = {
    IdentityPoolId: process.env.TenantIdentityPoolId,
    Logins: {
    'tenant.login': result[0].email
    },
    IdentityId: null,
    TokenDuration: 900 //900 = 15 minutes
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("here");
    cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(openIdParams, (err, 
    dataP) => {
        console.log("here 1");
        if (err) reject(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else resolve(dataP); // successful response
});
```

as you can see, I put console logs to see where it goes, and it never gets past the first "here".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: From an AWS support case that I have: "Cognito need to have internet access so Cognito cannot work in a VPC. We currently have a feature request for this as we have multiple customers run into the issue"

Comment: However that doesn't align with https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/64du5e/lambda_vpc_confusion/

It sounds like it needs to be in a NAT subnet with a Internet Gateway